# Provide a parameter for a custom template in SonataAdmin fields

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

I know how to set a custom template for a field in SonataAdminBundle. The following topic answer a question about that:

[Symfony SonataAdmin Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254316/symfony-sonataadmin-templates)

But, how can I pass a parameter to use in that template?

Answer (score 0):

You need [overriding Default Controllers](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html) and/or may be overriding Default Forms or [any Part of a Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/bundles/override.html)